# How can I import models from Anim8or into Blender?

Tags: import, file-format, external-applications

I am using [Blender](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_%28software%29) since I never liked the camera angle in [Anim8or](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anim8or). I recently picked up Blender and would like to use the wireframe model I had previously made.

I have searched for a way to move models from Anim8or to Blender but nothing so far. Is there a workflow for this or something that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transferring data is just a matter of finding a format that both programs can use. Some formats have better support for some features than others (like materials, animations, and armatures).

It would appear that Anim8or can export in [3DS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.3ds) and [OBJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) - both can be imported into Blender, menu *File* -> *Import* -> *3D Studio (.3ds)* or menu *File* -> *Import* -> *Wavefront (.obj)*.

Both import addons should be enabled in Blender by default, but if they aren't, open the User Preferences and look under addons to enable them.

I would export in both formats and see which one gives a better result in Blender. I would also expect that the mesh would transfer OK, but then expect to do some manual work to re-make the textures in Blender.

Comment: Sounds like this will work, I must have an older version of anim8or or I am blind because I don't remember seeing that as a save as option.

Comment: I Trying But It's Not Working I Really Am But This Is So Hard